# Construction GC Study - Summation of multiple multiplications in one formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on creating a general conditions (labor hour) study for a construction project. Its going to calculate the hours worked per employee based on how much of their time (%) is being charged to the job.

To calculate the total hours worked over the course of the job, I need the excel function to multiply each employee's % time allotted to the project with the number of working hours in the month, and then sum them all up. I have started the formula manually in the image below.

Is there a way to do this without going cell by cell?

[image]

Comment: Put `=SUM($K$5:$W$5)*E7` into `G7` and drag down (assuming you're using the percentages from column E?)

Comment: So Column F has my final burdened rate that I will charge clients for. For what is shown in the screenshots above, I am trying to calculate the total number of hours to be charged in the most efficient way. Row 5 has the number of hours per month, and columns K through Z has the % of time allotted per person for that month. Column G is supposed to sum up how many hours in total each person has worked. For instance, Column F Row 7, the 160 hours shown is (K5*K7)+(L5*L7). Im looking to sum up those pairs in a better way than going down the line of M5*M7 + N5*N7, etc.

Comment: I believe I have solved this by using the =sumproduct formula. In this instance, I was able to do =sumproduct(K5:L5,K7:L7)